# Google maps (API v2.0) for Android cannot be opened

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-manifest, forceclose

I am trying to do an application for Android which will use the Google Maps.

I thoroughly went through the basic tutorial from Google but my maps cannot be opened. When i used the different code it also didnt work.

Now I went step by step:

- Found SHA-1 key and created an API key for my application
- Changed the manifest file with all permissions and my new API key
- Added google-play-services-lib to buildpath

The program does not contain any errors. It doesn't even contain any maps but I only changed manifest file. So it should start but it doesn't start without errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hellnomap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

     <permission
        android:name="com.example.hellnomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" /> 

     <uses-permission android:name="com.example.hellnomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" > 
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

         <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" /> 

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            <!--
                 <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyCnxpVUcOtgFJCVOG3zmXDqauZ4F5m4Oos" />
            -->

            <activity
                android:name="com.example.hellnomap.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
     </uses-permission> 

</manifest>
```

When i try to load the program either on the phone or to an emulator Eclipse shows me that the loading is done and no errors but i do not see any application on any of them. It looks like it is not installed.

Here starts the interesting part: When i remove this part of the code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.hellnomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" >
```

I can easily install an application and it works. But i cannot add and load maps into it without this line.

What could be the problem? I already tried it with another applications from other tutorials (vogella, androidhive) they had samples and when i tried to run them - applications were forced closed.

Sorry for long post. Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

***Added:***

So, i have another app created from the tutorial. I also added everything there and it just force closes on start.

Logcat:

```
11-29 00:15:18.769: W/dalvikvm(7462): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13077: Lmy/newer/urbantry1/MainActivity;.getFragmentManager ()Landroid/app/FragmentManager;
11-29 00:15:18.809: W/dalvikvm(7462): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.newer.urbantry1/my.newer.urbantry1.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at my.newer.urbantry1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     ... 11 more
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/my.newer.urbantry1-2.apk]
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
11-29 00:15:18.819: E/AndroidRuntime(7462):     ... 20 more
```

And if the error could be in XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using all the new SDKs, added library and the right key for the manifest.
But somehow it causes error and cannot start..

Here's the manifest file for my application with the Google maps (not the first i mentioned):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.newer.urbantry1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="my.newer.urbantry1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="my.newer.urbantry1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="my.newer.urbantry1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCdcLhog-5M65Na17lancOwooLQSKKTTtI" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="my.newer.urbantry1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="my.newer.urbantry1.ShowMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_show_map" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your code snippet has the `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` meta data commented out - any chance you accidentally forgot to uncomment it after generating and adding in the map key? Also, you seem to be missing the [Play Services version meta data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_the_google_play_services_version_to_your_apps_manifest). Have a look in LogCat too - usually the Play Services library prints a hint in there in case anything bad happens.

Comment: Yes, meta-data was uncommented but still the program doesn't load to a device.
And there are no any messages in logcat. Only when i remove that lane - program starts and installed on a device as usual.

Comment: It's a bit of a long shot, but try clearing the app's data or removing it. In my experience, the map key tends to get cached on the device, which means if you initially deploy with the wrong key, this may affect future deployments with the correct one. Alternatively, the fact that other examples force close on you doesn't sound right. Perhaps you can provide some more details on the exact error - that might give a clue?

Comment: okay, i added the logs and some files on the app with maps interface which force closes on the start.

Comment: You're mixing the `MapFragment` and `SupportMapFragment` in the fragment tag. I'm guessing you'll want to use the latter only. Use the `android:name` attribute to specify which fragment should be instantiated by the framework (and get rid of the `class` attribute).

Comment: Your logcat error is far from complete. Look at the last "Caused by".

Comment: Okay, i updated the logcat information but still no luck here...